# Want to cast pandas column data type to string, if its having objectid - dynamically

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, pyarrow

I have a scenario all my Mongodb collections are having an objectId column. I am reading collections using pymongo and converting them into pandas dataframe.

When I try to write as parquet using
AWS lambda wrangler library or Pyarrow is failing with
`with type ObjectId: did not recognize Python value type when inferring an Arrow data type"`

Is there a way to convert objectId to string dynamically, if the column type is Objectid?

```
myresult = collection.find(query)
 wr.s3.to_parquet(df1,path="s3://abcd/parquet.parquet")
```

Sample mongo data  Schema

```
_id:objectID
id:string
createTimestamp: timestamp
updateTimestamp:timestamp
deleteTimestamp:timestamp
```

save as Parquet to Schema

```
_id:String
id:string
createTimestamp: timestamp
updateTimestamp:timestamp
deleteTimestamp:timestamp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to convert the `_id` column to string before saving it to parquet.

```py
wr.s3.to_parquet(
  df1.astype({"_id": str}),
  path="s3://abcd/parquet.parquet")
```